# Fade in jquery load call

Tags: jquery, load, fadein

I have a really basic question about jquery. However I don't know how to this so that's why i'm here looking for your help. This is my code:

**Edit:** `<a href="javascript:$('#target').load('page.html').fadeIn('1000');">Link</a>`

As you see i want to load page.html into a div called #target. What I also want to do wich doesen't work is to make page.html fade in when it loads. What's the right way to that?

Best Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you should put your Javascript code outside the element itself.  This is fairly simple to do.  It makes your HTML and Javascript much more easily comprehensible and ultimately allows much more organised code.  First, give your `a` element an `id`:

```
<a href='#' id='loadPage'>Link</a>
```

Then make your call in a `script` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { // when the whole DOM has loaded
        $('#loadPage').click(function(){ // bind a handler to clicks on #loadPage
            $('#target')
                .hide() // make sure #target starts hidden
                .load('page.html', function() {
                    $(this).fadeIn(1000); // when page.html has loaded, fade #target in
                });
        });
    });
</script>
```

---

**Edit** To comment, yes you can use a URL in the `a` tag and then use `this.href`.

```
<a href='page.html' id='loadPage'>Link</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#loadPage').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#target')
                .hide()
                .load(this.href, function() {
                    $(this).fadeIn(1000);
                });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks man! Works like a charm. Is it possible to make this dynamic by replacing page.html with something like "this.href"? and then have the url in the a href tag?

Comment: I don't really wanna be the one who is the one but when i use the above code it doesent load page.html into target. The browser redirects to page.html as if it was a basic link. Or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: I changed it to <a href="#" name="page.html" and used this.name. Doesen't seem valid but it worked :P

Comment: @Paparappa Sorry, forgot the `e.preventDefault()`.  Sorry!

Comment: @Ben Except that it is far less obvious what it means, makes multiple return points complicated and can easily fail if there is an error somewhere in the function. `preventDefault` is much nicer, IMO.

Comment: the use of hide() here was what i was looking for

Comment: 5 years later and this is helpful!!

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$('#target').load('page.html',{},function(){$('#target').fadeIn(1000)});
```

load has a complete handler ([see doc](http://api.jquery.com/load/))

Comment: p.s. You don't see inline jquery often these days :)